# Error Running Spark Glue jobs after created DF to tempView

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

```
 Explanation
```

when I am creating a DF from dynamic frame it works fine and I am able to write
dataframe back to dynamic frame but when I am converting a Dataframe to
createOrReplaceTempView then it is throwing me this error. The number of columns
are same and nothing has changed from the source  to the destination

Please help me what's going wrong

```
ERROR

IllegalArgumentException: "requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't 
match.\nOld column names (2): name, id\nNew column names (0): "
```

pysparkGlueCode

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import *



 args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['TempDir','JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database =   
"mygluedatabaseoregon", table_name = "dev_glue_poc_gluetable", redshift_tmp_dir =  
args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("name",  
"string", "name", "string"), ("id", "int", "id", "int")], transformation_ctx =   
"applymapping1")

selectfields2 = SelectFields.apply(frame = applymapping1, paths = ["name", "id"], 
transformation_ctx = "selectfields2")

getOutput = selectfields2.toDF() #.select('name','id')

getOutput.createOrReplaceTempView("info")

sqlData = spark.sql("select name,id from info")

outputSql = sqlData.toDF()

getOutputDFY = DynamicFrame.fromDF(outputSql,glueContext,"getOutputDFY")


resolvechoice3 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = getOutputDFY, choice = 
"MATCH_CATALOG", database = "mygluedatabaseoregon", table_name = 
"dev_glue_poc_importfromglue", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice3")



resolvechoice4 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = resolvechoice3, choice = "make_cols", 
transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice4")



  datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(frame = resolvechoice4, 
  database = "mygluedatabaseoregon", table_name = "dev_glue_poc_importfromglue", 
  redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink5")
  job.commit()
```